# Get the text of button when click on any one from buttons

Tags: c++, qt5

My application is very simple, I have two buttons, the first button its text `+`, and the second its text `-`.
Then, I want when click on any one of buttons, I receive the text of button that I have clicked.

And the following is the method that called when click on any one of buttons.

```
void Widget::btns_clicked()
{
        QPushButton *btn = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
        char _operator = btn->text();

        switch(_operator){
        case '+':
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Status", "You have clicked on (+)");
            break;
        case '-':
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Status", "You have clicked on (-)");
            break;
        }
}
```

But appear the following error message:
`cannot convert from 'QString' to 'char'`

**Also I have another small inquire**
is there is any other simplest way to do that:
`dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());` ?

Comment: `char` is one character. `text()` returns a string.

Comment: @chris:Thanks, but How to conversion.

Comment: Well, presumably, you'd want to make sure the string is one character and grab the first one.

Comment: @chris: I'm sorry, but I'm still beginner in Qt.

Comment: I've never used Qt. This is basic C++ in general. Single characters are separate from strings. I don't know offhand how `QString` lets you get the size or a single character, but it assuredly has a method for both.

Comment: @chris: I think the `Qt` is a little different from `C++`.

Comment: Well, I just looked and it seems to be about the same: `if (!str.isEmpty()) {first = str[0];}`

Comment: @chris: Thank you for your help, but really I want someone have a knowledge of `Qt`, because your code does not works fine, and also I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**btn->text()** returns **QString**, which is not a native C++ type, so you have to convert it into std::string first. If you look at the **QString** docs (e.g. via **Qt Assistant**) you'll see there the **toStdString()** function that does just that:

```
std::string _operator = btn->text().toStdString();
```

Also, notice that I've used string instead of char as you cannot assign string to char. But that's no problem since string is just an array of char elements, and thus we can use **_operator[0]** in the switch:

```
switch(_operator[0]){
    case '+':
...
```

That would solve your current problem and thus it ends the answer. One suggestion: why not use different slots for every button so that you immediately know which button has been clicked?

Also, you don't need a switch in your present code at all. You can just print information like this:

```
QMessageBox::information(this, "Status", "You have clicked on (" + _operator + ")");
```

and you'll always get the right message, no matter which button has been clicked.

Comment: Your explanation very clear, I'm now understood. thank you very much. What about the second inquire, if you know ?

Comment: As I've written in the answer, another way to do this is to create two separate slots for '+' and '-' button and connect the respective buttons to them; that way you don't have to cast anything as you know immediately which button has been clicked, because clicking the button would trigger the right slot. I don't know of any other option simplifying this.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean `dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());` is it possible to get the data that the sender holds without use `dynamic_cast`. for example `QPushButton *btn = sender();`. **Notice:** the code that in my question is just a small example to explain my problem, but it is not the real code that I used.

Comment: No, it is not possible since sender() returns QObject, which is the base type of many objects used in QT, and thus to access button-specific functions, such as text(), you need to tell the program that this object is of type QPushButton, so that the program can 'see' all the methods available for the button. If you don't cast, you will be able only to invoke methods belonging to QObject.